# How to edit subviews of a custom cocoa plugin

Tags: cocoa, plugins, interface-builder

If you add a custom view to a xib, then add a textfield, you can select the textfield and edit properties.

If I create a custom view as a plugin and it has a textfield as a child view, how do I edit the values of the textfield at design time when using the plugin?

Answer (score 0):

[- (NSArray *)ibDefaultChildren;](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/DeveloperTools/Reference/NSObjectIBAdditions_Reference/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSObject/ibDefaultChildren)